# Using jax-ws-catalog.xml for resolving imported xsd:s in wsdl

Tags: web-services, xsd, weblogic, jax-ws, catalog

I would like to deploy a Web Service using JAX-WS 2.1 on Weblogic where the wsdl imports a schema but I would prefer to have it in another location than together with the wsdl, preferrably it should be loaded from the classpath.

I was hoping I could use jax-ws-catalog.xml to map this but I cannot seem to get Weblogic to pick it up when deploying the application which then fails when the xsd cannot be found.

Maybe what I want to do is not possible and the catalog mapping is only used for Web Service clients, I have not found any clear documentation regarding this.

The import in the wsdl looks like this:

```
 <xs:import namespace="com.xyz.common/1.0"
schemaLocation="com.xyz.Common.1.0.xsd" />
```

The jax-ws-catalog.xml placed in the WEB-INF folder looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"
    prefer="system">
    <system systemId="com.xyz.Common.1.0.xsd" 
            uri="classpath:com.xyz.Common.1.0.xsd" />
</catalog>
```

As I said, this usage may not even be supported. I would be grateful for any pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the JAX-WS `jax-ws-catalog.xml` is supported if you publish your endpoint via [`sun-jaxws.xml`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/jaxws-war.html) (that means via `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener` et al). Looking at JAX-WS source code, I see that catalog is supported if one uses `W3CEndpointReferenceBuilder` / `Provider.createW3CEndpointReference()` (maybe [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-JAXsupport/index.html#N10095) will give you more information).

What I suggest you to do is to start Weblogic AS in debug mode and put breakpoints on two public static parse() methods of class `com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser`.